# toggle switch ngclass onclick with angularjs

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I want to change the class of a button when it clicked and also reverse back to its former state when its click again

```
$scope.like_btn = "icon ion-ios-heart";
$scope.like_btn2 = "icon ion-ios-heart assertive";
$scope.likepic=function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    if ($scope.like_btn === "icon ion-ios-heart"){
        $scope.like_btn = "icon ion-ios-heart assertive";

        $http.post("http://localhost/mywork/scripts/like.php",
        {'u_pic_id':$scope.u_pic_id})
        .success(function(data){
        console.log(data)
        });
        }

    else {
    $scope.like_btn = "icon ion-ios-heart assertive";
    $scope.like_btn = "icon ion-ios-heart";
    $http.post("http://localhost/mywork/scripts/like_delete.php",
    {'u_pic_id':$scope.u_pic_id})
    .success(function(data){
    console.log(data)
        });
    }
    }
```

HTML

```
<a href="#" ng-click="likepic()">Click to like</a>

<i ng-class="{ '{{like_btn}}': item.answer==='no liked','{{like_btn2}}':item.answer=='liked' }" ></i> {{item.love_total}} Likes
```

Comment: set a flag in your controller. and use it in html using ng-class eg   <button id="reset" class=" tooltipLuminance" ng-class="{fix_margin:!showbutton}"/> .. here fix_margin css is shown on basis of a flag

Answer (score 0):

Your 'item' is probably not getting updated after the service succeeded.
So one way is to add following to the controller:

```
$scope.item.isLiked = false; // or initiase it with item.isLiked
$scope.likepic=function(item) {
   item.isLiked = item.isLiked;
   ...
   ...    
}
```

Change your angular expression to the following :

```
<i ng-click="likepic(item)" ng-class="{ '{{like_btn}}': item.answer=='no liked','{{like_btn2}}': item.answer=='liked' }" ></i>
```

You need to update the varible names little bit.

Comment: just saw your answer but i've made update to the script. There is a text that has to be click to start the toggle

Comment: Fine, pass that angular object 'item' in the click function from which you are preparing the content i.e ng-click="likepic(item)". If that doesn't work that means 'item' is not a valid object there, please paste more template then to see what's happening.

Answer (score 0):

As I look at your case, the only change with onclick is that you are adding 'assertive' class. Below would be the approach.

Changes in the HTML View:

```
<a href="#" ng-click="likepic()">Click to like</a>
<i class="icon ion-ios-heart" ng-class="{'assertive': liked}" ></i> {{item.love_total}} Likes
```

Changes in Javascript

```
// Initialize the flag here
$scope.liked = false;

$scope.likepic = function() {
    event.preventDefault();
    // Toggle the flag here
    $scope.liked = !$scope.liked;
    // Then perform task as per the new value
    // There is some possibility of optimization below too. But since that is not the question, no changes are done here
    if ($scope.liked) {
        $http.post("http://localhost/mywork/scripts/like.php", { 'u_pic_id': $scope.u_pic_id })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
    } else {
        $http.post("http://localhost/mywork/scripts/like_delete.php", { 'u_pic_id': $scope.u_pic_id })
            .success(function(data) {
                console.log(data)
            });
    }
}
```